# listing IOs in Julia

Tags: io, julia

Lets say an environment redirects `stdout`, ignores the output, and then uses their own `IO` object to write to the screen:

```
const supersecretstdoutname = Ref{IO}()
# ...
function evironment_init()
    # ...
    supersecretstdoutname[] = stdout
    stdout = DevNull
    # ...
end
```

Would I have any way of finding `supersecretstdoutname` (or if they did something similar with `stdin`) without digging through source code?

Said another way, can I get a list of open `IO`s, or at least the ones that have access to the screen/user input?

Comment: what about using a Linux command to get the list of open files for a process e.g: `pfile 9999` where `9999` is the process id. The Julia process id can be obtained directly from Julia using the `getpid()` command.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to interface with the system or use the `JL_STD*`/`libuv` interface. But thanks!